# Display hostname next to IP on WiFi connection with wpa_supplicant and dhclient

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, hostname

I'm working on a custom Linux OS (built with Yocto) and I use `wpa_supplicant` to connect with Wi-Fi network and `dhclient` to get IP address. I can connect to the network and I can see my device from other clients and on the router admin panel, but instead of its name I can see Unknown. I would like to display it hostname value at this point. Could you pls give me an advice how to set it up?

On the device:

```
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500  metric 1
        inet 192.168.1.133  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 00:08:ca:df:23:e7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 17700  bytes 1808390 (1.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2935  bytes 674859 (659.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

On the router:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1LyZ.png)

On the other device:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.133
Host is up (0.0058s latency).
MAC Address: 00:08:ca:df:23:e7 (Unknown)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure dhclient is configured to send DHCP option 12 (Host name) in its lease requests.

**`dhclient.conf`**:

```
send host-name = gethostname();
```

Comment: Wow, as simple as that. Thank you very much! :D